# Hello Android works on my phone but not on Emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I am trying to learn about Android development. I have installed Eclipse (3.6.2) the ADT plugin (10.0.1) and the Android SDK (r11 off the official site) all are installed as 32 bit but my OS is Windows 7 64-bit.

What happens is I run my app (HelloAndroid) and the emulator and I see the main wallpaper screen but then then nothing happens! I have looked on the emulator for the app and cannot find it anywhere.

My console output is shown below...

```
[2011-05-20 19:14:20 - HelloAndroid] ------------------------------
[2011-05-20 19:14:20 - HelloAndroid] Android Launch!
[2011-05-20 19:14:20 - HelloAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2011-05-20 19:14:20 - HelloAndroid] Performing com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid activity launch
[2011-05-20 19:14:20 - HelloAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'Android2.1'
[2011-05-20 19:14:20 - HelloAndroid] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Android2.1'
```

My AVD (Android Virtual Device) is set up as the tutorial suggests and the target is Android2.1-update1-API Level 7.

I have installed this app on my phone (HTC Hero, Android 2.1) and it works fine, but before I try and write other applications I need to get the emulator working, has anyone encountered this issue before?

I have looked online and cannot find a solution that solves my problem.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: sorted it via the guide here - http://openhandsetmagazine.com/2008/01/tips-how-to-install-apk-files-on-android-emulator/ thanks to all who helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `adb` to install your app. Find the bin directory in your eclipse workspace. There should be a `YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.apk` file there. To install it, from the command line, run:

```
adb install -r YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.apk
```

You will need adb in your path.

Comment: tried this and i get the error: "error: device not found" the emulator is running when I try this

Comment: http://openhandsetmagazine.com/2008/01/tips-how-to-install-apk-files-on-android-emulator/ - I followed this guide to install the apk, but you were correct with what was required so I accepted your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Start the emulator, switch to the logcat view in Eclipse (Window -> show view -> other ... -> logcat).

Clear the console output for logcat.

Try to deploy your application.

What does the output in logcat say? Does it display an error message?

Comment: hi, nothing is displayed in logcat

Comment: Nothing? not even a single line?

Comment: That's odd. Sounds like your emulator some how is detached from Eclipse.

Comment: yeah, don't know. I think its odd. Might need to look at this a bit more but I have solved my initial issue